Header on top message in Thunderbird 115
In Thunderbird 115 the header for the newest message (top message) is not shown.  Is there a way to turn the header on the top message back on and restore the local toolbar with Reply / Reply All / etc. in addition to the distribution lists?
Thanks.

Are you able to include a screenshot of what you mean? Also which OS are you using?

Not sure how to add a screen shot.  Before the latest updates I had headers to each post which showed the date, the sender, the distribution lists, the subject, etc.  Now the top (newest) email stats with the email text.  The top message also had a built0-in toolbar with Reply / Reply All / etc.  That's gone, too.
